# How to forbid Pods in Namespaces without ResourceQuota using Gatekeeper?

Tags: kubernetes, open-policy-agent, rego

I want to forbid the creation of Pods in Namespaces which do not have a [ResourceQuota](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/). If possible, I want Gatekeeper to ensure that there is a ResourceQuota which sets `limits.cpu` and `limits.memory` before allowing the creation of Pods.

I have created below configurations, but they have not solved my problem:

**template**

```yaml
apiVersion: templates.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1 
kind: ConstraintTemplate 
metadata: 
  name: k8sresoucequota 
spec:
  crd:
    spec:
      names:
        kind: k8sResouceQuota
  targets:
    - target: admission.k8s.gatekeeper.sh
      rego: |
        package k8sresoucequota

        violation[{"msg": msg}] {
          input.request.kind.kind == "Pod"
          requestns := input.request.object.metadata.namespace
          existingrqs := {e | e := data.inventory.namespace[requestns]["v1beta1"]["ResourceQuota"].metadata.name}
          not ns_exists(requestns,existingrqs)
          msg := sprintf("container <%v> could not be created because the <%v> namespace does not have ResourceQuotas defined", [input.request.object.metadata.name,input.request.object.metadata.namespace])
        }

        ns_exists(ns,arr) {
          arr[_] = ns
        }
```

**Constraint**

```yaml
apiVersion: constraints.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1
kind: k8sResouceQuota
metadata:
  name: namespace-must-have-resourcequota
spec:
  match:
    kinds:
      - apiGroups: [""]
        kinds: ["Pod"]
    excludedNamespaces:
      - kube-system
      - kube-public
      - kube-node-lease
      - default
      - gatekeeper-system
      - kubernetes-dashboard
```

**sync.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: config.gatekeeper.sh/v1alpha1
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: config
  namespace: "gatekeeper-system"
spec:
  sync:
    syncOnly:
      - group: ""
        version: "v1beta1"
        kind: "Pod"
      - group: ""
        version: "v1beta1"
        kind: "Namespace"
      - group: ""
        version: "v1beta1"
        kind: "ResourceQuota"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1: "There is no ResourceQuota with the same name as the Namespace"**

Let's walk through these three lines of your Rego, one-by-one.

```
requestns := input.request.object.metadata.namespace
existingrqs := {e | e := data.inventory.namespace[requestns]["v1beta1"]["ResourceQuota"].metadata.name}
not ns_exists(requestns,existingrqs)
```

1. This line gets the name of the Namespace which holds the Pod being evaluated.

```
requestns := input.request.object.metadata.namespace
```

2. This line is invalid. Or rather, it will return an empty set.

```
existingrqs := {e | e := data.inventory.namespace[requestns]["v1beta1"]["ResourceQuota"].metadata.name}
```

I assume what you're trying to say is "get the name of every ResourceQuota in the same Namespace as the Pod.

Recall that [the format of data](https://open-policy-agent.github.io/gatekeeper/website/docs/sync) is `data.inventory.namespace[<namespace>][groupVersion][<kind>][<name>]`. So really the line should be:

```
existingrqs := {e | e := data.inventory.namespace[requestns]["v1beta1"]["ResourceQuota"][_].metadata.name
```

This will iterate through all ResourceQuotas in the Pod's Namespace, and create a set containing all of their names.

3. You have this split out as it's own function (`ns_exists`), but it looks like you're trying to find whether there is a ResourceQuota with the same name as the Namespace. Instead, you should use:

```
not existingrqs[requestns]
```

This statement will evaluate to `false` if the ResourceQuota of the same name exists, and `true` if it does not. But this is actually doing more than we need. We just care whether the ResourceQuota *exists*. We can combine lines 2 and 3 into:

```
not data.inventory.namespace[requestns]["v1beta1"]["ResourceQuota"][requestns]
```

This will evaluate to `true` if the ResourceQuota is missing, or `false` if there is such a ResourceQuota

The completed Rego should be:

```
package k8sresoucequota

violation[{"msg": msg}] {
  input.request.kind.kind == "Pod"
  requestns := input.request.object.metadata.namespace
  not data.inventory.namespace[requestns]["v1beta1"]["ResourceQuota"][requestns]
  msg := sprintf("container <%v> could not be created because the <%v> namespace does not have ResourceQuotas defined", [input.request.object.metadata.name,input.request.object.metadata.namespace])
}
```

In English, this will create a violation if the object is a Pod, and the Namespace does *not* contain a ResourceQuota of the same name as the Namespace.

**Part 2: "The ResourceQuota sets limits.cpu and limits.memory"**

For Rego, we use incremental rules to create OR conditions. While possible, it's considered an antipattern to circumvent that all statements in a Rego function are AND-ed together. So we need a different violation that checks that the ResourceQuota has `limits.cpu` and `limits.memory` set.

```
violation[{"msg": msg}] {
  input.request.kind.kind == "Pod"
  requestns := input.request.object.metadata.namespace
  data.inventory.namespace[requestns]["v1beta1"]["ResourceQuota"][requestns]
  rq := data.inventory.namespace[requestns]["v1beta1"]["ResourceQuota"][requestns]
  not defines_limits(rq)
  msg := sprintf("container <%v> could not be created because the <%v> namespace does not enforce limits.cpu or limits.memory", [input.request.object.metadata.name,input.request.object.metadata.namespace])
}

defines_limits(rq) {
  rq.limits.cpu
}

defines_limits(rq) {
  rq.limits.memory
}
```

This violation checks:

1. That a ResourceQuota of the desired name exists.
2. The ResourceQuota fails to set one of `limits.cpu` and `limits.memory`. That is, the ResourceQuota we found must set both in order to allow the Pod to be created.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58325979/2592962) does a good job explaining how incremental rules work.